# preserving extended attributes with cp/rsync

Tags: filesystems, rsync, cp, xattr

When copying with `cp`, the extended attributes are not preserved, even with explicit

```
cp -a --preserve=all /source /dest
```

or

```
cp -a --preserve=xattr /source /dest
```

The same is with `rsync`, i.e.

```
rsync -aq -A -X --delete /source /dest
```

However, on the destination filesystem, I can create extended attribute manually (with `chattr`). This means that the target filesystem supports xattr.

Why am I unable to preserve `xattr` with `cp` or `rsync` ?

## Additional information:

- Both source and target filesystems are ext4
- Both source and target filesystems are local (not nfs)
- I am using Debian Wheezy

Comment: How are you mounting this destination filesystem? Is it over NFS?

Comment: the destination filesystem is a local filesystem

Comment: Can you show the output of `mount` for this filesystem?

Comment: On what unix variant and version? What filesystem types at both ends, with what mount options?

Comment: since I am able to create extended attributes on the target filesystem manually (as explained in my initial question), I don't think the problem is caused by wrong mount options

Comment: what are the rsync versions on both systems

Comment: @Emmanuel - what do you mean "rsync versions on both systems" ? I am using one `rsync` to copy from `/source` to `/target`

Comment: @MartinVegter Could you give a sample attribute your file has? I just created ext4 filesystem in two files and did a test with `setfattr -n system.name0 -v "value" test_file`. I copied the `test_file` to/from ext4/jfs/xfs with `cp --preserve=all` and didn't have any issues preserving extended attributes.

Comment: Does `tar cfp` work?

Answer (score 18):

#### Update

After messing around with this some more and looking at the code for `chattr` and other `e2fsprogs`, it is clear that the attributes set by `chattr` and those set by `libattr` (eg with the command `setfattr`) are very different. `chattr` sets `ext` filesystem flags which simply do not map to an named attribute or namespace. *None* of them show up with any call to `libattr`'s  `listxattr`. They probably *should* map to named attributes in the `system` namespace as assumed below, but as of yet this is completely unimplemented. Also the `system.posix_acl_access` attribute I mistook for the mapping to one of these attributes below, is nothing to do with the `ext` filesystem flags and is rather to do with access control lists. The associated `strace` messages appear for any file and disappear when only `cp --preserve=xattr` is used.

It seems that the attributes set by `chattr` are specific to `ext` filesystems and that the only way to affect them is through `e2fsprogs` tools. In fact the `man` page does not actually use the term 'extended attributes' for them, but rather 'file attributes'. 'Real' extended attributes are name/value pairs which can be altered by `libattr` and are implemented on multiple filesystems. These are what `cp` and `rsync` look for and transfer over to copied files when the right options are given. It does however seem that `system` namespace exists to map the `chattr` attributes to names and ultimately to equivalent attributes on other filesystems, but for now this doesn't work.

I have left the original answer intact as there is some good information there, although it does go quite far wrong at points.

#### Update 2

I should have came back to this again before now, but as per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120049/48083), `chattr` works on more than just `ext` filesystems. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr), it is equivalent to the `chflags` command on BSD based systems.

I wrote a script to test the setting and reading of these attributes on a few filesystems and got the following results:

```
ext4:
suS-iadAcj-t-e-- mnt/test_file
suSDiadAcj-tTe-- mnt/test_dir

reiserfs:
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on mnt/test_file
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on mnt/test_dir

xfs:
--S-iadA-------- mnt/test_file
--S-iadA-------- mnt/test_dir

btrfs:
--S-iadAc------C mnt/test_file
--SDiadAc------C mnt/test_dir
```

Note that all attempts to read/set `reiserfs` file flags gave the above error, despite it being listed on Wikipedia as having some functionality. I did not test `reiser4`. Also while the `c` flag can set on `ext4` it is not honoured. There may also be tuning/mount options that affect these flags, but I couldn't find any.

It does however seem that currently `chattr` is the only utility on Linux capable of modifying these attributes and so no copy utility is capable of preserving them.

#### Original Answer

The reason for `rsync` seems to be that is doesn't even try. From the `-X` section of the `rsync` documentation:

```
For systems that support extended-attribute namespaces, a copy being done by a
super-user copies all namespaces except system.*.  A normal user only  copies
the user.* namespace.
```

<del>It is difficult to map the attribute letters used by `chattr` and `lsattr` to the underlying named attributes used in the filesystem (for one there is no list on the internet). From my tests though, the `A` attribute maps to the `system.posix_acl_access` attribute and since this is the `system` namespace, `rsync` won't even try to copy it.</del> The other two namespaces not mentioned in the `man` snippet are `trusted` and `security`, root privileges are required to set these (and `rsync` won't try without).

Most likely the attributes you have tried to set fall in the `system` namespace which `rsync` ignores (and probably wisely). Either that or you need to be root to get the ones that aren't.

<del>As for `cp`, there appears to be bugs at play.</del> Running `strace` on `cp -a`, I get the following two interesting lines:

```
fgetxattr(3, "system.posix_acl_access", 0x7fff5181c0e0, 132) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)
```

and

```
fsetxattr(4, "system.posix_acl_access", "\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x06\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x04\x00\x04\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff \x00\x04\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff", 28, 0) = 0
```

<del>Firstly the `fgetxattr` call doesn't return any data (probably because there isn't any - the existence of the attribute is enough), yet somehow `cp` finds 28 bytes of (junk?) data to set as the attribute value in the destination file. This seems like a bug in `cp`, but rather what is causing the issues seems to be a bug in `libattr` as the `fsetattr` call returns `0` for success without actually setting the attribute.</del>

I get this behaviour on `ext4` regardless of whether I mount with `user_xattr`. I can't find any documentation on this other than to say that 'some systems' need this mount option for extended attributes to work. Seemingly mine (Debian Jessie) doesn't. Even there is a mounting issue I have missed, it is wrong for `fsetattr` and thus `cp` to fail silently.

**Actually `user_xattr` is needed on `ext2`, `ext3`, `reiserfs` and possibly some others. It is not necessary for `ext4`**

Note also that the `attr` tools `setfattr`, `getfattr` and `attr` (the latter is documented to be only for `XFS` only, but seems to work just as well as the others for `ext4`) have problems working in anything but the `user` namespace. I get `Operation not supported` if I try to use `setfattr` to put an attribute in the the `system` namespace (or no namespace as per this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-source-2.6.15/+bug/43954)). `setfattr` appears to succeed in the `trusted` and `security` namespaces, but then `getfattr` fails to read anything back and also fails to read anything from the `system` namespace set by `chattr`. The reason that `chattr` succeeds is that it uses an `ioctl` call and not `libattr`.

What does work perfectly though, is setting extended attributes in the `user` namespace with `setfattr` and using `rsync` or `cp` to copy with them intact (there are even no issues with `cp` if you don't specify a value when creating the attribute). I think the bottom line is that using `system` namespace values is currently <del>buggy and/or</del> unsupported, at least in Debian and probably other distros too. Likely the `rsync` developers know this, which is why they ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

#### Q: `Why am I unable to preserve xattr with cp or rsync ?`

I'll restrict my answer to `rsync`:

`rsync` will now preserve your extended attributes (`xattr`). Under the heading `--xattrs, -X` in `man rsync` (ver 3.2.4), the paragraph cited in the [previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119980/286615) now reads as follows:

> For systems that support extended-attribute namespaces, a copy being done by a super-user copies all namespaces except  system.*.   A  normal user only copies the user.* namespace.  To be able to backup and restore non-user
> namespaces as a normal user, see the --fake-super option.

According to the [rsync website](https://rsync.samba.org/), the `--fake-super` option was added in [rsync ver 3.0.0 in 2008](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/NEWS#3.0.0).

I no longer have a Debian `wheezy` system, but I have tested this feature/option on my Debian `buster` & `bullseye` systems. It works for me, but just to be clear, my *"[rsync m.o.](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/modus+operandi)"* may be different from yours: I keep my systems in sync using an *intermediary* NAS device; i.e. `host1 <--> NAS <--> host2`. This arrangement provides a collateral backup facility also.

Here's an outline of what I do;

`$SOURCE_DIR` - a folder I define on the system that contains the source (original) data
`$DEST_BKUP` - a folder I define on the intermediary/backup NAS appliance
`$DEST_DIR` - a folder I define on the system that contains a copy of the source data

On the sourcing system:

```bash
$ rsync -rlAXtgoDvi --fake-super $SOURCE_DIR/ $DEST_BKUP
```

On the receiving system:

```bash
$ rsync -rlAXtgoDvi --fake-super $DEST_BKUP/ $DEST_DIR
```