# Difference between xattr and chattr

Tags: linux, files, inode, xattr

What is the relation and the difference between `xattr` and `chattr`? I want to know when I set a `chattr` attribute in Linux what is happening inside the Linux kernel and inode metadata.

Comment: I wrote a long answer on a related question yesterday which might be helpful - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118840/preserving-extended-attributes-with-cp-rsync/119980. Note that the `attr` command is intended for XFS filesystems, the equivalent filesystem independent command is `setfattr`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The attributes as handled by `lsattr`/[`chattr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr) on Linux and some of which can be stored by quite a few file systems (ext2/3/4, reiserfs, JFS, OCFS2, btrfs, XFS, nilfs2, hfsplus...) and even queried over CIFS/SMB (when with POSIX extensions) are flags. Just bits than can be turned on or off to disable or enable an attribute (like *immutable* or *archive*...). How they are stored is file system specific, but generally as a 16/32/64 bit record in the inode.

The full list of flags is found on Linux native filesystems (ext2/3/4, btrfs...) though not all of the flags apply to all of FS, and for other non-native FS, Linux tries to map them to equivalent features in the corresponding file system. For instance the [simmutable](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chflags.1.html) flag as stored by OSX on HFS+ file systems is mapped to the corresponding immutable flag in Linux `chattr`. What flag is supported by what file system is hardly documented at all. Often, reading the kernel source code is the only option.

Extended attributes on the other hand, as set with `setfattr` or `attr` on Linux store more than flags. They are attached to a file as well, and are key/value pairs that can be (both key and value) arbitrary arrays of bytes (though with limitation of size on some file systems).

The key can be for instance: `system.posix_acl_access` or `user.rsync.%stat`. The `system` namespace is reserved for the system (you wouldn't change the POSIX ACLs with `setfattr`, but more with `setfacl`, POSIX ACLs just happen to be stored as extended attributes at least on some file systems), while the `user` namespace can be used by applications (here `rsync` uses it for its `--fake-super` option, to store information about ownership or permissions when you're not superuser).

Again, how they are stored is filesystem specific. See WikiPedia for [more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes).

Comment: Do `lsattr`/`chattr` work for non `ext` filesystems? If not how would you change the flags on non `ext` systems on Linux? Also the `attr` man page says that it is written for XFS (even though it works for me on `ext4`). I actually spent a long time looking into this yesterday, good information is hard to come by. Please see - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118840/preserving-extended-attributes-with-cp-rsync/119980

Comment: @Graeme, answers to those questions are in my answer. `lsattr/chattr` are for file flags. Not all flags are supported by all filesystems, for instance, some of them like compression won't work on ext4 but will work on btrfs.

Comment: If you are interested, I wrote a script to test these flags on a few filesystems and put the results on my answer linked above. I had no success setting/reading any of them on `reiserfs`.

Answer (score -1):

Everything have been stroed in `inode`.When you change a file, indeed you change its `inode`.for scripting you have a good command :

```
stat --format=%a yourfile
```

You can use `%variable` and return a useful from `inode`

**But your answer:**

`xattr` is on the MacOS and `chattr` on linux box.